# Rewrite to pretty links with nginx

Tags: php, nginx, url-rewriting

Basically the question is how to make this url

http://domain.com/folder/cache.php?a=3a1c2aa4d440d3d8ce4207b07488ae4d?g=67h

to look like this

http://domain.com/folder/3a1c2aa4d440d3d8ce4207b07488ae4d?g=67h

Comment: So you don't want your site to work? Do you not want to specify a page atleast or provide a variable for that session looking string? Do you really want your url to look like this `http://domain.com/folder/cache?a=8329f8d9sfadfds&g=67h`?

Comment: $a is not a session string, its a hashed value i need

Comment: regardless... how is your site supposed to know the hash belongs to a and not z?

Comment: because the hash is always first, so i thought it was possible to cut it in 2 parts http://domain.com/folder/cache.php?a= and 3a1c2aa4d440d3d8ce4207b07488ae4d?g=67h

Comment: will this always go to cache.php and a will always = a hash?

Comment: think of it like `$var= '3a1c2aa4d440d3d8ce4207b07488ae4d?g=67h?b=herp?c=derp';
http://www.domain.com/folder/cache.php?a=.$var.`
Hash is always first and after that they may be different parrameters

Comment: do you mean to use & instead of all those ?'s? EDIT: So you want all those ?='s included into the hash?

Comment: i mean that for cache.php everything including the hash and the parameters next is one big string that are all stored in $a. So i just wanted to make it look like i said above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked

`rewrite ^/folder/(.*)$ /folder/cache.php?a=$1?$args? last;`

Answer (score 0):

```
rewrite ^/folder/(.*)$ /folder/cache.php?a=$1$is_args$args? last;
```